# Missing Dock after updating to Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.04, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, dock

Can't find my Dock after upgrade to **Ubuntu 19.04** (available only when I open *Activities*)
Dock settings are present:

[image]

Extension itself is installed:

[image]

Can anyone help and tell me what might cause the issue?

**UPD:**
Reinstall didn't help:

```
sudo apt purge gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

**UPD2:**
*Tweak tool* shows that there is an error loading extension for **Dash to Dock**:

[image]

Comment: have you installed gnome-tweaks app to see the installed extensions and available opti0ns..

Comment: Just checked. It is installed but with *Error loading extension* for **Dash to Dock**

Comment: 0k..its already known issue... how did you install dash to dock extension?

Comment: so the answer is that it's not compatible with 19.04?

Comment: no no.. its solved.. see the accpected answer..

Comment: there are different workarounds to make the dash to dock work properly in Ubuntu 19.04..

Comment: That solves my issue. Thanks! The only confusion is that accepted answer says: **Note: DtD is not compatible with 19.04**

Comment: that means.. as per my understanding manual installation 0nly w0rks without any problems.. command line or via software center it does not work..